# Запрос на выборку mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Вывести посещения месяца с полной информацией врача с наименьшим количеством посещений за определенный период.

В общем, я написал запрос, который выводит врачей и посещения за определенный период

```
select visit_id, 
        pets.name as pet_name,
        concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as vet_name, 
        visit_date,
        visits.description,
        services.name,
        price
from visits
join vets on visits.vet_id = vets.id
join pets on visits.pet_id = pets.id
join visit_details on visits.id = visit_details.visit_id
join services on visit_details.service_id = services.id
where visit_date between '2019-02-10' and '2019-03-02'
order by visit_date, price
```

Вот что получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как из этих записей оставить только те фамилии (vet_name) которых наименьшее количество?

Вот вся схема базы, но все таблицы я уже объеденил в запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *оставить только те фамилии (vet_name) которых наименьшее количество?* Вот кто бы мне объяснил, что эта фраза должна значить...

Comment: @Akina, Извините за невнятность) Моим запросом я получил список проведенных "операций" каждым врачем. Мне нужно оставить только записи с тем врачем,у которого наименьшее количество "операций"

Comment: Ааа... ну так добавьте поле `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY vet_name)`, сортировку по этому полю, и LIMIT 1.

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо, чисто из интереса, как переделать мой запрос, чтобы получить другие варианты исполнения данного запроса?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не запускал, так как у меня нет данных, но выглядеть это должно приблизительно так:

```
create view view1 as
select visit_id, 
        pets.name as pet_name,
        concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as vet_name, 
        visit_date,
        visits.description,
        services.name,
        price
from visits
join vets on visits.vet_id = vets.id
join pets on visits.pet_id = pets.id
join visit_details on visits.id = visit_details.visit_id
join services on visit_details.service_id = services.id
where visit_date between '2019-02-10' and '2019-03-02'
order by visit_date, price;

create table table1 as
select 
  vet_name, 
  count(vet_name) as cnt
from view1
group by vet_name;

create table table2 as
select 
  vet_name
from table1
where cnt = (select min(cnt) from table1);

select vet_name 
from table1
where vet_name in (select vet_name from table2);
```